# WebPack + WebExtensions/Chrome Extension - getBackground() not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a Firefox/Chrome Addon/Extension with the same codebase by utilizing the [WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions) and the [web-extensions-browser polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webextension-polyfill) (through webpack and RequireJS).

I noticed [Firefox requires code to be unobfuscated and unminified when submitting a version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Source_Code_Submission), and thus had to install the `unminify-webpack-plugin` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unminified-webpack-plugin).

The last hindering issue I have is that since webpack includes all the required files in one file (as it usually does), the functionality for `browser.extension.getBackground()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getBackgroundPage#Examples) doesn't work, as all my functions in my `background.js` are added to an anonymous module function.

Any suggestions on how I'd go about solving this?

**Edit 1: Here's some more insight**

My folder structure is as follows:

```
plugin/
├── wepback.config.js
├── manifest.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── node_modules/
├── *dist/
├── img/
│   ├── icon.png
│   ├── ... etc
├── src/
│   ├── background/
│   │   ├── background.js
│   │   └── background.html
│   └── popup/
│       ├── popup.js
│       └── popup.html
```

Where my config is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var UnminifiedWebpackPlugin = require('unminified-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    background: './src/background/background.js',
    popup: './src/popup/popup.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name]/[name].min.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: './src/background/background.html', to: 'background/background.html'},
      { from: './src/popup/popup.html', to: 'popup/popup.html'},
      { from: './src/popup/popup.css', to: 'popup/popup.css'},
      { from: './manifest.json', to: 'manifest.json'},
      { from: './img', to: 'img/[name].[ext]'},
    ]),
    new UnminifiedWebpackPlugin()
  ],
};
```

**Edit 2:**

Found the following boiler plate which looks promising. This does seem like an issue that, once solved, can just be reused - so I'll try it out soon and move my project over and test.

https://github.com/fstanis/webextensions-webpack-boilerplate

Comment: I'm not familiar with webpack but AFAIK you need to configure it to build background.js separately and I believe there should be many examples around (in case no one answers here soon).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm - by 'build background.js seperately`, I already have it configured to build and copy over my resources - but it seems the bundling is messing with the scope of the functions I had in my original background/popup files :( I'll post my config to give some further clarity

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work around this is using the extension API's message system, with the  [sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) function and [onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) event - or the port system. See chrome's tutorial on [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) for more information.

Alternatively, you can access the `window` object directly in your background page - for example, with `window.foo = 'bar'`. Then `getBackgroundPage()` will work as expected. Directly mutating or accessing variables across contexts is slightly bad practice, and I'm guessing accessing variables through the `window` object may be as well, but I think it's probably fine as this is what `getBackgroundPage()` is intended for anyway.